# Laravel AJAX Pagination brings up rows from old data

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-pagination

I have a table which contents I want to order from Z-A alphabetical order once a button is clicked.

This works alright. I had the problem at first the pagination links I returned where not correct. Fixed those so I got no 404 page thrown at me anymore. But now When I click the next page button. The table will just go to the next page of the old unordered data.

my sort function:

```
 function Sorting($column, $direction)
{
    $data = $this->db->GetAll("mid"/* table */, "40" /* rows for pagination*/, true/*paginate*/, true,/*sorting*/ "$column" /* column to be sorted on*/, "$direction" /* ASC or DESc */);
    $Fields = $this->db->GetFieldnames("mid", false); // Field names for the table.
    $data->setPath("http://localhost:8000/dashboard/beheer/marketing"); // setting the correct path for the pagination otherwise an 404 error would be thrown.
    $returnview = view("Beheer.Dashboard.components.Marketing.tableLeads")->with('Leads', $data)->with('MidTableFields', $Fields)->render(); // returning it to the view.
    echo json_encode($returnview); // returning it to the Ajax call.
}
```

my view:

```
 <?php
  /**
  * Created by PhpStorm.
  * User: Entric
  * Date: 14-6-2018
  * Time: 15:43
  */
 ?>
 <div>
     <table class="table" id="tablemid">
         <thead>
         <tr>
             @foreach($MidTableFields as $field)
                 @if($field === 'id')
                     @php
                         $field = 'MID';
                     @endphp
                 @endif
                 <th id="{{$field}}"><a onclick="Sort(this.id)" href="# 
                 {{$field}}" id="{{$field}}">{{$field}}</a></th>
             @endforeach
         </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody id="LeadsContentTable" style=>
         @foreach($Leads->reverse() as $lead)
             @if($lead->Actief == 1)
                 @php
                     $active = 'Ja';
                 @endphp
             @else
                  @php
                     $active = 'Nee';
                  @endphp
             @endif
             <tr class="tableRow" id="row{{$lead->id}}">
                 <td id="mid">
                      {{$lead->id}}
                 </td>
                 <td id="company">
                {{$lead->Bedrijfsnaam}}
            </td>
            <td id="contact">
                {{$lead->Contactpersoon}}
            </td>
            <td id="email">
                {{$lead->Email}}
            </td>
            <td id="tel">
                {{$lead->Telefoon}}
            </td>
            <td id="ip">
                {{$lead->IP}}
            </td>
            <td id="active">
                {{$active}}
            </td>
            <td id="note">
                {{$lead->Notitie}}
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" id="{{$lead->id}}" onclick="EditLead(this.id);" data-toggle="modal"
                   data-target="#LeadModalEdit">
                    <button class="btn btn-neutral btn-icon btn-round button">
                        <i class="material-icons" style="color:rgba(223,176,0,0.79)">mode_edit</i>
                    </button>
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" id="{{$lead->id}}" onclick="GetDeleteLead(this.id);" data-toggle="modal"
                   data-target="#LeadModalDelete">
                    <button class="btn btn-neutral btn-icon btn-round button">
                        <i class="material-icons" style="color:rgba(185,14,22,0.81)">clear</i>
                    </button>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
 </div>
 <div class="pagination">
     {{ $Leads->links("pagination::bootstrap-4")}}
 </div>
```

The JS Function that iniates the sort:

```
 function Sort(identifier){
            let sorter = 'asc';
            if(sorter === 'asc'){
                sorter = 'desc';
            } else if(sorter === 'desc'){
                sorter = 'asc';
            }
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: '/SortLeads',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    const token = jQuery('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
                    if (token) {
                        return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
                    }
                },
                data: {id: identifier, sorter: sorter},
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#tablecont").empty();
                    $("#tablecont").append(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

### Update

This is how my controller function looks now.

```
     function Sorting($column, $direction)
{
    $data = $this->db->GetAll("mid"/* table */, "40" /* rows for pagination*/, true/*paginate*/, true,/*sorting*/"$column" /* column to be sorted on*/, "$direction" /* ASC or DESc */);
    $Fields = $this->db->GetFieldnames("mid", false); // Field names for the table.
    $paginator = $data->appends(['sort' => $direction ])->setPath("http://localhost:8000/dashboard/beheer/marketing")->links();
    $returnview = view("Beheer.Dashboard.components.Marketing.tableLeads")->with('Leads', $data)->with('MidTableFields', $Fields)->with('pager', $paginator)->render(); // returning it to the view.
    echo json_encode($returnview); // returning it to the Ajax call.
}
```

And my paginator in my view looks like:

```
@if(!isset($pager))
{{ $Leads->links("pagination::bootstrap-4")}}
@elseif(isset($pager))
{{$pager}}
@endif
```

This loads in the new paginator, and I know it's another one since it isn't styled with Bootstrap 4.

The paginator loads in with the options set in controller. But it still doesn't show the data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my request type of my sort request to GET. I changed the url of the paginator to: domain.nl/dashboard/beheer/marketing/sortleads.

```
 let sorter = 'desc';
        function Sort(identifier){
            if(sorter === 'desc'){
                sorter = 'asc';
            } else if(sorter === 'desc'){
                sorter = 'asc';
            }
            if(identifier == "MID"){
                identifier = "id";
            }
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $.ajax({
                url: '/dashboard/beheer/SortLeads',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    const token = jQuery('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
                    if (token) {
                        return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
                    }
                },
                data: {id: identifier, sorter: sorter},
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#tablecont").empty();
                    $("#tablecont").append(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

I made a check on which parameters were send in the function the ajax request fires in the AjaxController.

Sorting function in my AjaxController.

```
  public function LeadSort(){
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $this->marketingController->Sorting($_GET['id'], $_GET['sorter']);
    } else {
        $paginator = \Session::get('pager');
        $arrayoptions = \Session::get('data');
        $data = $this->db->GetAll("mid", "50" , true, true, $arrayoptions['col'], $arrayoptions['dir'] );
        $Fields = \Session::get('fields');
        return view("Beheer.marketing")->with('Leads', $data)->with('MidTableFields', $Fields)->with('pager', $paginator)->render();
    }
}
```

Here I check if an ID is being send. If so. This means it's the first time something will be sorted. ID refers to the column header name. so if company name is being clicked it will sort on company name.

I check what column has been set by `$_GET['id']` and check what direction needs to be sorted by `$_GET['sorter']`. These 2 value's I put in 2 session variables for later usage in the Sorter function of MarketingController. And I generate the sorted Data and put it in an html table, in this function I also load the table field names of the table that's being sorted and load/render the paginator and put it in a session variable.

Eventually I use the data and render it in a view. Which will be returned and appended by the Ajax Success function.

Here's the Sorter function of MarketingController.php

```
 function Sorting($column, $direction)
{
    $data = $this->db->GetAll("mid", "50", true, true,"$column", "$direction");
    $Fields = $this->db->GetFieldnames("mid", false);

    $paginator = $data->appends(['sort' => $direction ])->render("pagination::bootstrap-4");
    \Session::put('pager', $paginator);
    \Session::put('data', ["col" => $column, "dir" => $direction]);
    \Session::put('fields', $Fields);


    $returnview = view("Beheer.Dashboard.components.Marketing.tableLeads")->with('Leads', $data)->with('MidTableFields', $Fields)->with('pager', $paginator)->render(); // returning it to the view.
    echo json_encode($returnview); // returning it to the Ajax call.
}
```

But what if we want to paginate through the table? when a pagination button is clicked, no ID is being send. so it will try to get the all the values I've put in session variables. And I reuse them the get my data and render a new view. Which will produce the 2nd or whatever page clicked on by the paginator. Which also will be appended by the Ajax success function

### Downside of this solution:

I haven't figured out why and how to fix this issue produced by this solution. But the problem now is: If you press on the e.g. 3rd button of the paginator. The correct data will be loaded. But the paginator won't be updated to make the 3rd button active.

Immense props to Begmuhammet Kakabayev. For helping me out and setting me on the right path to the complete solution!

Answer (score 1):

It is because `{{ $Leads->links("pagination::bootstrap-4")}}` creates links according to old parameters.
At first `$direction` paramter is 'asc' so Laravel creates links according to those parameters. You should add to your variable direction parameter.
Something like this. `{{ $Leads->appends(['sort' => 'desc'])->links() }}`
I don't know how to do it after `ajax request`. Maybe you just refresh page with new `parameters` when `sort button clicked`

You should do something like this

```
success: function (data) {
           var rows = data.rows
           var paginator_links = data.links // you will produce this in backend

           $("#tablecont").empty();
           // $("#tablecont").append(data);
           $("#tablecont").append(rows);

           // here you will replace links
           $('.pagination').empty();
           $('.pagination').append(links);
         }
```

Comment: Will look into it. Just saw your answer pop up on my inbox. I will comment my results back later :) Thanks !

Comment: Just for testing purposes and later implementing it correctly. I set my paginator in my tableLeads views as : `{{ $Leads->appends(["sort" => 'desc'])->links("pagination::bootstrap-4")}}` Still the same results. It still fetches the old data and returns the 2nd page of it.After clicking my sort button and then clicking the paginator.

Comment: I know. That's why I said maybe you should refresh page. It is because you update table after the page loads. When page loads your php code is compiled. And {{ $Leads->appends(['sort' => 'desc'])->links() }} this produces result with link where 'sort' is 'desc' and it stays the same whatever you do with javascript.

Comment: Shortly. Here is my advice. when you load data with ajax produce {{ $Leads->appends(['sort' => 'desc'])->links() }}  this in backend. and replace it in the front end. Don't know if I could explain it. Sorry for poor english

Comment: See my updated Question. I think this is the way to implement it dynamically. But it still doesn't work however.. The paginator does get replaced. But it still does not show the data I want when another page is loaded..

Comment: No that won't do work. I'll update my answer look at it.

Comment: If paginator does get replaced, maybe the problem is where you call the function 'Sorting' wrong parameter or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173401/discussion-between-begmuhammet-kakabayev-and-rick-jellema).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I found a solution to my problem. Will post it as an answer.